# Error barplot after running library (plyr)

Tags: r

I have the following dataset

```
set.seed(42)
cancer <- sample(c("yes", "no"), 200, replace=TRUE) 
agegroup <- sample(c("35-39", "40-44", "45-49"), 200, replace=TRUE)  
agefirstchild <- sample(c("Age < 30", "Age 30 or greater", "nullipareous"), 200, replace=TRUE) 
dat <- data.frame(cancer, agegroup, agefirstchild)
```

And I am running this code to create a barchart. 2 questions.
1.I would now like to have the chart for the whole dataset not only cancer = yes
2. After I did run the library(plyr) I received a warning it wasn't working with a specific package.
Below plot was working, but after running this library not anymore. This is the error message: "Error in print.default(m, ..., quote = quote, right = right, max = max) :
invalid 'na.print' specification"

```
riskwoinvasivetrain%>%
 group_by(Agegroup) %>%
 summarize(prop_cancer = mean(Cancer == 'yes')) %>%
 print(n=1000)
```

And just would like to have a simple frequency table telling me the size (n) of each subgroup. E.g size age 35-39 is

`````
'data.frame':   159093 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ Menopause              : chr  "Postmenopausal" "Postmenopausal" "Postmenopausal" "Postmenopausal" ...
 $ Agegroup               : chr  "45-49" "45-49" "45-49" "45-49" ...
 $ Density                : chr  "Almost entirely fat" "Almost entirely fat" "Almost entirely fat" "Almost entirely fat" ...
 $ Race                   : chr  "white" "white" "white" "white" ...
 $ BMI                    : chr  "10-24.99" "10-24.99" "10-24.99" "10-24.99" ...
 $ AgeFirstBirth          : chr  "< 30" "< 30" "< 30" "< 30" ...
 $ NumberRelativesCancer  : chr  "zero" "zero" "zero" "zero" ...
 $ PreviousBreastProcedure: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ LastMammogram          : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SurgicalMenopause      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ HRT                    : chr  "no" "no" "no" "no" ...
 $ Cancer                 : chr  "no" "no" "no" "no" ...````
`````

Comment: I think you need to group by 'Cancer'.  In the code, the column names are different.  what should be the column names corresponding to the input example

Comment: I need to have a result for BMI for the complete dataset . This code now limits to results for BMI for only people that have Cancer Yes

Comment: In the example you showed, there is no column 'BMI'

Comment: Ok have adjusted text to clarify

Comment: Perhaps you meant `dat %>% count(agegroup, cancer) %>% mutate(prop_cancer = n/sum(n))`

Answer (score 1):

We can take the `count`, divide by the `sum` of 'n' for percentage and then do the plotting with `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat %>% 
    count(agegroup, cancer) %>% 
    mutate(prop_cancer = n/sum(n)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = agegroup, y = n, fill = cancer)) +
        geom_col()
```

Comment: I keep on getting strange errors, when running this code The variables and dataset names in my code are correct I checked 10 times but it doesn't recognize agegroup cancer . Another code with exactly the same name work. Might be related to plyr pacckage installation. See original message This is the error     Error in count(., Agegroup, Cancer) : object 'Agegroup' not found

Comment: @Kirsten Can you try on a fresh R session with only `dplyr` loaded.  I guess with `plyr` loaded, it is using `plyr::mutate` instead of `dplyr::mutate`

Comment: I would love to, but when I restart I think I lose all my results . Or is there a way I can restart without losing results? Perhaps I need to stick with my other bargraph which is less beautiful

Comment: @Kirsten yes, you can just replace the mutate with `dplyr::mutate(prop_cancer = n/sum(n))` and also I guess `dplyr::count`

Comment: Like this? I get an error  library(dplyr)
`library(ggplot2)
riskwoinvasivetrain%>% 
  count(Agegroup, Cancer) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(prop_cancer = n/sum(n))
  ggplot(aes(x = Agegroup, y = n, fill = Cancer)) +
  geom_col()`

Comment: @Kirsten I meant `dat %>% dplyr::count(agegroup, cancer) %>% dplyr::mutate(prop_cancer = n/sum(n))`

Comment: This is the error I get    Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument? This is the code used  `riskwoinvasivetrain%>% 
  dplyr::count(Agegroup, Cancer) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(prop_cancer = n/sum(n))
  ggplot(aes(x = Agegroup, y = n, fill = Cancer)) +
  geom_col()`

Comment: @Kirsten Okay, so the data is not `data.frame` and it is not related to the packages.  can you show the `str(riskwoinvasivetrain)` and do `as.data.frame(riskwoinvasivetrain) %>%`

Comment: I'll restart my R when I don't need the results anymore and then try out your code. Think that is easier.  Adding as.data.frame gives the same error. Just not so nice packages are developed that are making other packages unworkable

Comment: @Kirsten can you show the `str(riskwoinvasivetrain)` so that I understand what is going on in the structure

Comment: @Kirsten I agree with your comment that there are a lot of dependencies when you use external packages and some functions mask similar functions from other packages

Comment: It is added in my original post

Comment: @Kirsten It says that it is a `data.frame':   159093 obs. of  12 variables:`.  So, I am confused why you have that error.  May be your env got corrupted with loading packages.  Clean the env and don't save the env while exiting

Comment: Yes I go check once I can clean up in R. Currently can't lose results